# how to write the mail body in aligned format in javamail

Tags: java, escaping, jakarta-mail, chars

I will collect all the data from the database and put them inside a collection. I want to put all the data in that collection into my javamail body in the properly aligned format illustrated below. How should I put the list data inside the body content:

```
  EmployeeName:Ranjeeth.
  Login Time:09:30.
  Logout Time:18:30.
```

by using escape chars how to write in string?

Comment: could anybody plz help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most common way to do this, is to create an email template with data placeholder. At runtime fill the data in the template and then use the complete text in the java mail body.

Step wise:

1. Create a template file say mailBody.txt in the project. The content could be like this:

   EmployeeName: ##EMP_NAME##.

   Login Time:##LOGIN_TIME##.

   Logout Time:##LOGOUT_TIME##.
2. Read this file content in a string at runtime, so that :

   See this [How to really read text file from classpath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)

Read content from inpitstream

```
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("test");  // or your input stream
    byte[] b = new byte[is.available()];
    is.read(b);
    String text = new String(b);
    //System.out.println(text);

`String s = <content of the file>`
```

3. Prepare the data from database and then replace the String content placeholders like:

`s = s.replace("##EMP_NAME##", <emp name value from database>)`

`s = s.replace("##LOGIN_TIME##", <login time value from database>)`

`s = s.replace("##LOGOUT_TIME##", <logout value from database>)`

4. use the String s for the email body content.

You can add any kind of formatting, tabs, spaces etc in the template and your program would change the email text seamlessly.

---

Edit: To Repeat a certain part again and again:
If you have simple data to repeat, just think about creating it inline like:

```
StringBuilder temp=new StringBuilder("");
for(loop to repeat the content){
temp.append(<Emp Name value from database>).append("\n\t\t")
.append(<login time value from database>).append("\n\t\t")
.append(<logout time value from database>).append("\n\t\t");
}
```

make template like:

> Hi,
>
> Below is the details of users:
>
> $#EMP_DETAILS#$
>
> Thanks, Your Name

Read the template into string variable

```
String s = <content of the file>;
```

then

```
s.replace("$#EMP_DETAILS#$", temp.toString());
```

You should be all set.

Comment: am very new to it could u plz elaborate it...

Comment: Which step you are not getting?

Comment: where should i create that template file..in my project

Comment: At any location in class path.. even inside a package should be ok, and just read it like a file ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("/path/file.ext");

Comment: i have to create my file in .txt format

Comment: I got that file now can u plz explain me about reading content and replacing that content

Comment: that like is fine that every thing is works fine in that like,but i need how read that content and put inside string

Comment: String s = <content of the file> how to read this content once get that file

Comment: updated the content to read data from an input stream.

Comment: i got that content also but i could not able to replace the content bcz the strings  are immutable

Comment: thanks now that replacing that content also working fine, now i want to loop over same content several times would it possible

Comment: Now think over all the template the possibilities with template and string replacement, and you should be able to create whatever you want and whatever format you wish. You must think about upvoting and accepting the answer.

Comment: added more hints towards repeating a content.